# How to change ipa version in expo react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

actually i'm facing error of version code when i upload app in applestore, i'm updating the app now i need to update its version too. I have checked both file app.json and package.json in both file i found version but confuse both are different then each other so its maybe an issue maybe i'm changing another version rather then app.

**app.json:**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "noorzoo",
    "description": "noorzoo",
    "slug": "noorzoo",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "33.0.0",
    "version": "2.0", --i change it
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "primaryColor": "#cccccc",
    "icon": "./assets/icons/app.png",
    "facebookScheme": "fb455325908675514",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "packagerOpts": {
      "assetExts": [
        "ttf",
        "mp4"
      ]
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "assets/**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "xxxx",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "buildNumber": "2",
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "xxx",
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "xxx"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "xxx",
      "versionCode": 4,
      "permissions": [
        "CAMERA",
        "NOTIFICATIONS",
        "CAMERA_ROLL",
        "READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
      ]
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  },
  "updates": {
    "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
    "checkAutomatically": "ON_LOAD"
  }
}
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "Noorzoo",
  "version": "2.0.0", --this is i change
  "description": "Noorzoo",
  "author": "Esattosoft",
  "private": true,
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",

}
```

this is what i'm getting while uploading ipa in apple store
[image: li]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change version in app.json to 2.0.0. and rebuild the new ipa.
On iOS, this corresponds to CFBundleShortVersionString.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work on expo, hence I may not have the similar settings like you do. However to tackle your question, you can simply update your **version** and **build number** in Xcode.

1. Click on your project
2. Under General Tab - (update Version and Build)